# Crash on Xcode Run

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, exception, crash

i run project that imported from Unity3D.
then at XCode i try to run to my iPad.

Apps can builded and installed but when running it crash (sometime just blank screen).

at Xcode i got below error, but i dont understand what these error means ?

```
CrashReporter: initialized
2018-10-23 11:11:36.341 flashcards[318:26427] -> registered mono modules 0x1ee2e00
-> applicationDidFinishLaunching()
2018-10-23 11:11:37.789 flashcards[318:26427] Metal GPU Frame Capture Enabled
2018-10-23 11:11:37.790 flashcards[318:26427] Metal API Validation Disabled
-> applicationDidBecomeActive()
Renderer: PowerVR SGX 543
Vendor:   Imagination Technologies
Version:  OpenGL ES 2.0 IMGSGX543-124.1
GLES:     2
GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap GL_OES_mapbuffer GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_debug_label GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_EXT_draw_instanced GL_EXT_instanced_arrays GL_EXT_map_buffer_range GL_EXT_occlusion_query_boolean GL_EXT_pvrtc_sRGB GL_EXT_read_format_bgra GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch GL_EXT_shader_texture_lod GL_EXT_shadow_samplers GL_EXT_sRGB GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_texture_rg GL_EXT_texture_storage GL_APPLE_clip_distance GL_APPLE_color_buffer_packed_float GL_APPLE_copy_texture_levels GL_APPLE_framebuffer_multisample GL_APPLE_rgb_422 GL_APPLE_sync GL_APPLE_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_APPLE_texture_max_level GL_APPLE_texture_packed_float GL_IMG_read_format GL_IMG_texture_comp
ression_pvrtc 
OPENGL LOG: Creating OpenGL ES 2.0 graphics device ; Context level  <OpenGL ES 2.0> ; Context handle 359353072
Initialize engine version: 2017.4.8f1 (5ab7f4878ef1)
WARNING: 0:4: extension 'GL_EXT_frag_depth' is not supported
ERROR: 0:38: Use of undeclared identifier 'gl_FragDepthEXT'

Note: Creation of internal variant of shader 'Hidden/Internal-MotionVectors' failed.
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/Internal-MotionVectors' - Pass '' has no vertex shader
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/Internal-MotionVectors' - Setting to default shader.
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/BlitToDepth' - Pass '' has no vertex shader
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/BlitToDepth' - Setting to default shader.
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/BlitToDepth_MSAA' - Pass '' has no vertex shader
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/BlitToDepth_MSAA' - Setting to default shader.
WARNING: 0:4: extension 'GL_EXT_frag_depth' is not supported
ERROR: 0:14: Use of undeclared identifier 'gl_FragDepthEXT'

Note: Creation of internal variant of shader 'Hidden/BlitCopyWithDepth' failed.
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/BlitCopyWithDepth' - Pass '' has no vertex shader
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/BlitCopyWithDepth' - Setting to default shader.
The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object 'Scene Variables') is missing!

(Filename:  Line: 1758)

The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object 'Scene Variables') is missing!

(Filename:  Line: 1758)

The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object 'IAPManager') is missing!

(Filename:  Line: 1758)

The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object 'IAPManager') is missing!

(Filename:  Line: 1758)

The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object 'IAPManager') is missing!

(Filename:  Line: 1758)

UnloadTime: 9.446791 ms
2018-10-23 11:11:45.250 flashcards[318:26427] *** Assertion failure in -[UnityDefaultViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations], /Users/mac/Downloads/snowy_eng_ios_noads/Classes/UI/UnityViewControllerBase+iOS.mm:93
2018-10-23 11:11:48.218 flashcards[318:26427] Uncaught exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException: UnityDefaultViewController should be used only if unity is set to autorotate
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x20a37933 <redacted> + 150
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x201d2e17 objc_exception_throw + 38
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x20a377f1 <redacted> + 0
    3   Foundation                          0x2121b529 <redacted> + 92
    4   flashcards                          0x0008849f -[UnityDefaultViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations] + 302
    5   flashcards                          0x000a2ce3 -[UnityAppController application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:] + 174
    6   flashcards                          0x0128d0f8 GADiTunesMetadataForFileAtPath + 12068
    7   flashcards                          0x01348570 GADODiskUsageStatisticsWithError + 3488
    8   flashcards                          0x0134848c GADODiskUsageStatisticsWithError + 3260
    9   flashcards                          0x01252f84 GADOCategories_NSArray_GADOJSONAdditions + 15060
    10  flashcards                          0x013112cc GADODispatchAsyncSafeMainQueue + 64
    11  flashcards                          0x01252e40 GADOCategories_NSArray_GADOJSONAdditions + 14736
    12  flashcards                          0x01143531 -[GADURewardBasedVideoAd loadRequest:withAdUnitID:] + 78
    13  flashcards                          0x011403ff GADURequestRewardBasedVideoAd + 76
    14  flashcards                          0x00278c4d RewardBasedVideoAdClient_LoadAd_m483440913 + 34
    15  flashcards                          0x0026c8ab RewardBasedVideoAd_LoadAd_m4208741079 + 90
    16  flashcards                          0x0023bdaf z_reward_ads_Start_m1587933392 + 102
    17  flashcards                          0x010f0ce5 _Z31RuntimeInvoker_Void_t1185182177PFvvEPK10MethodInfoPvPS4_ + 10
    18  flashcards                          0x01d66793 _ZN6il2cpp2vm7Runtime6InvokeEPK10MethodInfoPvPS5_PP15Il2CppException + 118
    19  flashcards                          0x016d91b3 _Z23scripting_method_invoke18ScriptingMethodPtr18ScriptingObjectPtrR18ScriptingArgumentsP21ScriptingExceptionPtrb + 66
    20  flashcards                          0x016dffdd _ZN19ScriptingInvocation6InvokeEP21ScriptingExceptionPtrb + 38
    21  flashcards                          0x016e4a73 _ZN13MonoBehaviour30InvokeMethodOrCoroutineCheckedE18ScriptingMethodPtr18ScriptingObjectPtrP21ScriptingExceptionPtr + 1198
    22  flashcards                          0x016e4bd1 _ZN13MonoBehaviour30InvokeMethodOrCoroutineCheckedE18ScriptingMethodPtr18ScriptingObjectPtr + 46
    23  flashcards                          0x016e3f3d _ZN13MonoBehaviour16DelayedStartCallEP6ObjectPv + 46
    24  flashcards                          0x01578339 _ZN18DelayedCallManager6UpdateEi + 430
    25  flashcards                          0x0162b699 _Z10PlayerLoopv + 520
    26  flashcards                          0x0147fb0d _ZL19UnityPlayerLoopImplb + 22
    27  flashcards                          0x000915c5 UnityRepaint + 220
    28  flashcards                          0x0009147d -[UnityAppController(Rendering) repaintDisplayLink] + 76
    29  libMTLInterpose.dylib               0x05cec865 -[DYDisplayLinkInterposer forwardDisplayLinkCallback:] + 276
    30  QuartzCore                          0x23093a0b <redacted> + 106
    31  QuartzCore                          0x23093857 <redacted> + 594
    32  IOMobileFramebuffer                 0x2277a50b <redacted> + 86
    33  IOKit                               0x20c88759 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 256
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x209e637d <redacted> + 132
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x209fa5b3 <redacted> + 34
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x209f9cc7 <redacted> + 342
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x209f80d9 <redacted> + 1688
    38  CoreFoundation                      0x20947229 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
    39  CoreFoundation                      0x20947015 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
    40  GraphicsServices                    0x21f37ac9 GSEventRunModal + 160
    41  UIKit                               0x2501b189 UIApplicationMain + 144
    42  flashcards                          0x00087f9f main + 206
    43  libdyld.dylib                       0x205ef873 <redacted> + 2
```

and i got exception at here :

```
gsCrashReporterUEHandler    NSUncaughtExceptionHandler *    (flashcards`uncaught_exception_handler) 0x01bf1a38
```

any idea, what error i found here ?

Comment: It more or less tells you exactly what the issue is "Uncaught exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException: UnityDefaultViewController should be used only if unity is set to autorotate"..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your crash log I can see this error:
Uncaught exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException: UnityDefaultViewController should be used only if unity is set to autorotate.

This means Unity should set Screen.orientation to ScreenOrientation.AutoRotation.

You can check if some code in your Unity3D project set the Screen.orientation to any other code and check in "Unity Build setting" Default Orientation is "Auto Rotation".

Answer (score 2):

We got this crash report also, and many of them

I've read somewhere (maybe in Unity forum) that it's being caused by Ads that showing in different orientation, when the game is back from Ads, the orientation did not restore correctly so Unity log the ASSERT.

They suggested that we just need open the exported XCode project and comment out the ASSERT line 111 in the file `UnityViewControllerBase+iOS.mm`

Well, we did and it's working for us!!!

[image: comment out the ASSERT line 111 in the file UnityViewControllerBase+iOS.mm]

---

```
//
// Just in case the attached screenshot expires
//
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    //NSAssert(UnityShouldAutorotate(), @"UnityDefaultViewController     should be used only if unity is set to autorotate");

    return EnabledAutorotationInterfaceOrientations();
}
```